# epoch time for GMT

Tags: date, timestamp, unix-timestamp, aix, timezone-offset

On **AIX**

`date -u` gives date and time in GMT format 
`date` gives date and time in local timezone 
`date +%s` gives local time in epoch time

Is there a way to get GMT time in epoch format?

In the AIX I'm using, there are only -n and -u options available (so I'm unable to use -f option).

My aim is to calculate Offset in hours between localtime and GMT. 
I can parse `$TZ environment variable` which can be tedious. Instead divide epoch time difference between two times by 60 should approximately give me the answer.

Comment: 1) epoch is not a format but a point in time (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`) 2) what about `date +%z`?

Comment: Just to ask the probably obvious, can't you do `date -u +%s` ? (Sorry, I don't have access to AIX anymore (and it can be very different than the Linux-ens most of are used to now). ), Good luck!

Comment: The trouble you face is that the number of seconds since the Epoch is the same for both local time and UTC.  To determine the time zone offset, you would have to determine the difference between the time-formatted outputs, which is painful at best.  As @marekful suggested, look for `%z` support; that should give you a ±hhmm time zone offset from GMT (with negative being west of UTC — so in the US/Pacific time zone, on Mac OS X, `date +%z currently gives -0700, which is the offset for Pacific summer (daylight saving) time).

Comment: @shellter, date -u +%s and date +%s gives same number.

Comment: @SandyR : Thanks for checking and letting us know. As usual, JohnathanL understands the vagaries of this issue. Does AIX have `+%z`? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, JonathanL. On AIX I'm using, date +%z gives me name of the zone: TAIST, CEST, etc,. without offset info.

Comment: sorry, but "That's AIX for you" :-( ... Can you get GNU utils installed? You may also get more AIX specific help by joining the AIX forum on http://ittoolbox.com. Its an easy registration. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what you state `date +%s` does not 'give local time in epoch time'. Epoch is the moment in time that AIX (UNIX) time starts counting (in the time_t structure). Timestamps in `time_t` are given in seconds since epoch, not counting leap seconds. This is what `date +%s` returns. From the `date` man page:

```
   %s
        Displays the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time (CUT).
```

On AIX parsing TZ is not as tedious as you think. Unlike Linux and other UNIX systems the way that TZ is built up on AIX is always `std offset dst offset , rule` so the following should work to extract the current offset from TZ:

```
echo $TZ | sed -e 's/.*'`date +%z`'\([-0-9:]*\).*/\1/'
```

However I think the best and easiest solution is a mini C program that displays what you want:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  tzset();
  printf("%d\n", timezone);
}
```

Example:

```
$ cc -o tz_offset tz_offset.c
$ TZ=CET-1CEST-2 ./a.out
-3600
$ TZ=EST5EDT ./a.out
18000
```

For more information see:

- `man environment`
- `man date`
- `man ctime`

Comment: A note: Aix6+ does support Olson-database so TZ=Europe/Budapest is perfectly valid.

Comment: My AIX knowledge (and hardware) doesn't go further than 5.3, thanks for the info!